# After fetching the access token to perform API requests on user's behalf, whats the "proper" way to keep the user session and token connected?

Tags: session, cookies, oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver4

I'm currently developing an identity 4 server, an API protected by scopes defined on the identity server and the mobile app server which will consume information from the API.

By now I already got a good grasp of how to use the authorization and access tokens and how to perform the correct flows, however I got into a dilemma when I started looking at the user session between the mobile app and server. After receiving the access and identity token, which basically serves as confirmation of user login/authorization, which would be the "proper" way to store it and keep the session alive with the app?

Initially I thought of using using cookies, but was told it doesn't work well with mobile apps (I barely know anything about android/ios), to which I followed by considering the creation of JWT on the server, which seemed wrong considering the existence of the identity server that was already producing tokens. And with this, how would I related the session to the access token to perform the API requests?

TLDR:

- After fetching access and id token for the client, what "proper"
  methods are there to keep sessions alive between client and mobile app?
- How to relate the session to the access token to use when API requests are necessary?

Thanks !

Comment: Is your mobile app a "native" one, or it is a web app hosted in a browser shell?

Comment: This app is native but we are treating it as a third party app/server to access the protected API, since that would be the end objective.

Comment: So you don’t need a cookie anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a modern native mobile app I'd suggest using the authorization_code flow (via the default browser on the device) with PKCE and storing a refresh token in the secure enclave of the device. This can then be protected by built in PIN or biometric features.

With that (carefully protected) refresh token you can maintain a long lived session without the need to do front channel (i.e. web browser) interactions with the OIDC service.

Comment: So, if i understood correctly, I keep the authorization code in the server (from which i fetch the access code), and pass the refresh token onto the device and store it protected there.  With the refresh token on the device, It would be possible to re-establish the session without the need of user input (other than a pin as suggested) and the session has the token to access API. However i still have a question: After sending the refresh token to reestablish a session, how do I keep it alive, a short lived cookie? Or do I use the token created from the refresh to communicate with the server?

Comment: You'd use the access token you obtained via the refresh token to communicate with your backend. When it expires you can use the refresh token to get a new token without any user interaction. In effect the reference token is your "session" and there way well be no cookie-authenticated session on the IDP at all.

Comment: Sorry the late reply, i think i understood the proper way to do this! thanks !!